# Using GPU for number-crunching and rendering at the same time in parallel

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, rendering, opencl, gdi

Can rendering job and number-crunching job (f.ex. on OpenCL) be effectively shared on the same single GPU? For example,

1. thread A runs OpenCL task to generate an image
2. then, when image is ready, thread A notifies another thread B (image is ready) and continues to new image calculation
3. thread B starts some pre-display activities on a given image (like overlay calculation with GDI), combines final image and render it to display

Can this kind of GPU resource sharing get performance improvement or, on the contrary, will cause to overall slowdown of compute and rendering tasks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is many factors involved here, but generally, you shouldn't see a slowdown.

Problems with directly answering your question:

- OpenCL could be using your CPU as well, depending on how you set it up
- Your gfx stuff could be done mostly on CPU or a different part of the GPU, depending on what you display ; for example, many GDI implementations render using the CPU, and only use very simple 2D acceleration techniques on the GPU, mostly to blit the final composed image.
- It might depend on the GPU, GPU driver, graphic stack etc. you use.

As most of the time, you will get the best answer for this by trying it out, or at least benchmarking the different parts. After all, you won't really get much of a benefit if your computations are too simple or the image rendering part is too simple.

Also you might try going even further and rendering the result with shaders or the like - in that case you could prevent having to move the data back from the gpu memory to main memory, which could - depending on your circumstances - also give you a speed boost.

Answer (score 0):

if data/crunching ratio is big and also if you have to send data from cpu to gpu:

crunch ---> crunch ----> render

```
GPU  th0        :  crunch for (t-1)     crunch for (t)         rendering
CPU  th1        :  send data for t      send data for t+1      send data for t+2
CPU  th2        :  get data of t-2      get  data of t-1       get data of t
CPU th3-th7     :  Other things independent of crunching or rendering.
At the same time:  crunching&comm.      crunching&comm.        rendering&communication
                   and other things     and other things       and other things
```

if data/crunching ratio is big and also if you dont have to send data from cpu to gpu:

```
 use interoperatability of CL (example: cl-gl interop)
```

if data/crunching ratio is small

```
 should not see any slowdown.
```

Medium data/crunching ratio:  crunch --> render --->crunch ---> render

```
GPU th0         :  crunch for  (t)      rendering              crunch for (t+1)         render again! and continue cycling like this
CPU th1         :  get data of (t-1)    send data for t+1      get data of (t)
CPU th2-th7     :  Other things independent of crunching or rendering.
At the same time:  crunching&getting.   rendering&sending.     crunching&getting
                   and other things     and other things       and other things
```

Comment: If I get you right, 1) for non-heavy or simple computation, running GPU-based computation in one thread and rendering in another - should not see any slowdown, 2) for heavy computation on GPU - it is better to use the same thread for computation and rendering. Correct?

Comment: No, both rendering and crunching is in same thread : thread-0 :) So no waiting between them. But there need to be a sync between thread 0 and other threads. For heavy  version, only the ratio of  crunching/rendering is changed and getter/senders are in different threads.